# Proving the order of a fourth order multi-step method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> **Prove:** that the explicit multistep method
>   \begin{equation}
> \label{eq:Multi-step method 4th order}
> y_{n+3}+\alpha_2 y_{n+2}+\alpha_1 y_{n+1}+\alpha_0 y_n=h[\beta_2f(t_{n+2},y_{n+2})+\beta_1f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})+\beta_0f(t_{n},y_{n})]
> \end{equation}
>   is fourth order only if $\alpha_0+\alpha_2=8$.

I have included the work that I have done so far:

I use the following theorem (for which I cannot find the a name for):

**Theorem:** A multistep method is of order $p \geq 1$ if and only if there exists $c \neq 0$ such that $$\rho(w)-\sigma(w)\ln(w)=c(w-1)^{p+1}+O(|w-1|^{p+2}) \quad w \rightarrow 1$$

We begin by finding the values of $\rho(w)$ and $\sigma(w)$:
\begin{align*}
& \rho(w)-\sigma(w)\ln(w) \\
&= w^3+a_2w^2+a_1w+a_0-(b_2w^2+b_1w+b_0)\ln(w)\\
&\text{ replaced $w$ with $\xi +1$, and expaned $\ln(w)$ as a taylor series} \\
&= \left( \xi +1 \right) ^{3}+a_{{2}} \left( \xi +1 \right) ^{2}+a_{{1}} \left( \xi +1 \right) +a_{{0}}- \left( b_{{2}} \left( \xi +1 \right) ^{2}+b_{{1}} \left( \xi +1 \right) +b_{{0}} \right)( \xi-\xi^2/2+\xi^3/3-\xi^4/4+\xi^5/5+O(\xi^6))
\end{align*}
From there I am unsure how to proceed, except that I need to show that if $\alpha_0+\alpha_2=8$ and $\alpha_1=-9$ is true than the about statement should be equal to $c\xi^5+ O(\xi^6)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want a term without $β$ construct a function that is zero on the sample points. For symmetry, choose $-h,0,h$ as $t_0,t_1,t_2$. For further simplification set $h=1$, then a possible function is $$f(t)=4t(t^2-1).$$ As it is of degree $3$, the numerical integration of order 4 has to be exact. The exact solution is $$y(t)=t^4-2t^2.$$ Now evaluate at $n=0$, $t_n=n-1$, to get
$$
y(2)+α_2y(1)+α_1y(0)+α_0y(-1)=0
\\
8+α_2·(-1)+α_1·0+α_0·(-1)=0
$$

Comment: Sorry I am having a little trouble understanding your answer. 1) Why is the R.H.S equal to zero. 2) $8+α_2·(-1)+α_1·0+α_0·(-1)=0$ shows that $α_2+α_0·=8$, put how can we show that $α_1=9$ (as there are no restrictions on value of $α_1$ in the answer above.  3) An arbitrary function was chosen so how can we show  that the conditions on alpha must hold for all possible $f$.

Comment: Because $f(-1)=f(0)=f(1)=0$. And because of consistency, or in detail, set $f(t,x)=0$, solution $y(t)=1$ gives $1+α_2+α_1+α_0=0$.